# Have Pantone Number, Now How Do I Find In Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, print-design, pantone

I have selected a Pantone color from a Pantone book, let's say 285 C, now I want to make my artwork to that Pantone color and ready for print. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Swatches Window top right menu, follow this path:

Open Swatch Library → Color Books → Pantone Solid Coated

[image]

At the Pantone window search field, type the color number:

[image: 285C]